Fourier & Fejer's partial sums
I am reading a calculus book about Fourier series and I'm stuck on some simple algebra:
Here $\sigma_n = \frac{S_1 + ... + S_n}{n}$ is the n-th Fejer's sum.
$|S_n(f, x) - \sigma_{n-1}(f,x)| = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}{\frac{|k|\hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}}{n}}$
$S_n = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}{\hat{f(k)}e^{ikx}}$
where $\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(t)e^{-int}dt}$
I feel bad asking such a simple question, but could you please explain me, how this algebra trick equality works? I can't see it!

\begin{align}
&|S_n(f, x) - \sigma_{n-1}(f, x)|
\\
&= \left|
S_n(f, x)
- \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} S_m(f, x)
\right|
\\
&= \left|
\sum_{k=-n}^n \hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}
- \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=-m}^m \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}
\right|
\\
&= \left|
\sum_{k=-n}^n \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}
- \sum_{k=-(n-1)}^{n-1} \frac{n-k}{n} \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}
\right|
& \text{change order of double sum}
\\
&= \left|
\sum_{k=-n}^n
\frac{k}{n} \hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}
\right|.
\end{align}
This is similar to your right-hand side, but I can't see how to justify pushing the absolute value inside the sum.

Details on the double sum: with $g(k) = \frac{1}{n} \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx}$, write out the double sum and keep track of how many times each $g(k)$ appears.
\begin{align}
&\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=-m}^m g(k)
\\
&= g(0)
\\
&\qquad + g(-1) + g(0) + g(1)
\\
&\qquad + g(-2) + g(-1) + g(0) + g(1) + g(2)
\\
&\qquad \vdots
\\
&\qquad + g(-(n-1)) + g(-(n-2)) + \cdots + g(n-2) + g(n-1)
\\
&= g(-(n-1)) + 2g(-(n-2)) + \cdots + (n-2) g(-2) + (n-1) g(-1) + ng(0) + (n-1) g(1) + (n-2) g(2) + \cdots + 2g(n-2) + g(n-1)
\\
&= \sum_{k=-(n-1)}^{n-1} (n-k) g(k).
\end{align}

your result is completely fine! I can bound it above with $\sum_{k=-n}^n
\frac{|k|}{n} \hat{|f(k)|}$ and I will get what I need. could you just please enlighten me a bit about this change of order trick that you did? I guess I'm already tired, but it does not seem obvious to me

@myfakeaccount Updated my answer
